# Kendo UI Angular Global Search

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Just short question, I have tried to look around on how to do the global search for `Kendo UI Angular`. What I mean by `global search` is, outside the kendo table have a text field, then we type anything in field then the kendo table will load and search the data.

I have done this using `Kendo Angular Jquery` but yet till now I can't find the solution on how to do the `global search` on `Kendo UI Angular`

If someone had done with this, can share me how to do the `global search` for `Kendo UI Angular` table.

note: I'm using `angular 4` for my current development.

many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any feature like that other than filtering rows.
You could create your own filter to achieve this, since after all, you're just feeding a data array to kend-grid

So I'd create a searchInput Pipe, that takes keyword argument

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData | searchInput: keyword">
```

1. Build a custom pipe, and feed it the data array, as well as arguments like substring

I'm guessing you already have a model.. something like this

```
export class DeviceType {
  constructor(
    public deviceId: string,
    public deviceType: string,
    public currentUser: string
  ) {}
};
```

you can use filter function, and feed it a callback function that compares argument input with each  data element. Note in this example were only comparing two things, you can easily do it with several members.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'searchData'
})
export class SearchData implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: DeviceType[], arg: string): any {
    return data.filter(item => {
      if (arg) {
        const searchInput = arg.toLowerCase();
        const deviceId = item.deviceId.toLowerCase();
        const deviceType = item.deviceType .toLowerCase();

        if(deviceId.includes(searchInput) || deviceType .includes(searchInput)){
          return item;
        }
      }
});
```

}
}

2. Create the input form and feed it as an argument to the
3. Pipe your input data, and feed the argument with string entered in input.

Comment: @lancovici Hi thanks for the answer. but can you show me some working example in `plunker`? I'm worried If I can't achieve your idea.

Comment: @FaiZalDong, You haven't shared any code, so I don't know how you've setup your project. If you start up a project on plunker or stackblitz, I'll show how to integrate a pipe.